# Node.js + Express app in Azure hits 500 errors that fix themselves

Tags: node.js, azure, express, web-applications

I have a Node.js 4.4.7 app using Express 3.4.4 that has this mysterious issue. If I navigate to `www.mydomain.com` sometimes I'm met with a 500 server error. It is important to note that the home page here makes a DB call. Immediately after this happens if I navigate to `www.mydomain.com/login` the page renders fine. No DB transactions occur on this page. From the login page, I can press `Home` in the navigation bar and I'll be brought to `www.mydomain.com/` and the page renders fine.

It's almost as if the DB or Web App instance go to sleep and need to be awoken. So I enabled `Always On` in my application settings but this has not resolved the problem. I also created a few alert tests that push some traffic to the site so it never goes to sleep. This helped a bit but occasionally I get the alert email that my ping test has failed still.

When a ping test fails, I am able to immediately go to `www.mydomain.com/login` successfully, then navigate to "Home" from that page successfully. A few minutes later I get a notification that my app state is "Healthy again.

#### Route for `mydomain.com/`

```
exports.index = function (req, res) {
var query = "SELECT P.pid, P.title, P.tags, P.topic, P.body_preview FROM Posts P ORDER BY P.date_created DESC";

new req.sql.Request().query(query, function (err, recordset) {
    if (err) throw err;

    res.render('index', {
        rows: recordset
    });
});
```

#### Route for `mydomain.com/login`

```
exports.g_login = function (req, res) {
    res.render('auth/login');
}
```

Similarly, I have the site setup to deploy directly from my GitHub repository. Whenever I push to my master branch the site usually hits a 500 error for a few minutes then is fine. I KNOW it's not from breaking code because this can be duplicated by simply committing a comment in any file.

I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637272/windows-azure-node-js-internal-server-error) which seems to experience similar symptoms, placing the fault on the Azure load balancer.

#### Azure Log Stream

My site was working fine right now, but to get the log stream to show an error I performed the following steps.

- `cd MyApp/`
- `echo "test" >> delete-me.txt`
- `git add delete-me.txt`
- `git commit -m "test to make 500 error"`
- `git push`

And as soon as I refreshed my website, to no surprise it hits a 500 error. I opened up the logs and this connection error is shown in the `mssql` Node module. Again, I was able to fix the 500 error by going to `mydomain.com/login` and then navigating to `mydomain.com/`.

```
Express server listening on port \\.\pipe\7a9d4df2-518e-4eb1-afbe-74064c927cbf
Sat Oct 14 2017 23:17:24 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time): Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
ConnectionError: Connection is closed.
    at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mssql\lib\main.js:1569:17
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
```

This is the code that connects to the DB from my `app.js`

```
var sql = require("mssql");

// Setup for Azure SQL Server
var config = {
    user: env.username,
    password: env.password,
    server: "mydomain.database.windows.net",
    database: "blog",

    // As per the npm docs, encrypt=true for Azure connections
    options: {
        encrypt: true
    }
};
sql.connect(config, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

Also of note, I have never hit this error when plugged into my Azure db but working locally, it is only the deployed version of my app that experiences this. I have read through [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql/issues/138) where many people are experiencing this problem. Is there any solution out there?

**EDIT** Adding middleware that reveals the SQL object.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    req.highlight = highlight;
    req.sessions = sessions;
    req.bcrypt = bcrypt;
    req.sql = sql;
    req.md = md;
    req.fs = fs;
    next();
});
```

Comment: how do you get the sql in the req object of express, do you define a middlware, if yes - please show it

Comment: @ShimonBrandsdorfer added the appropriate middleware that reveals the SQL object.

Comment: Doesn't the Request have to be inside the callback of Connect? Please have a look on my answer

Comment: @ShimonBrandsdorfer once you've connected your sql object you can make a sql.Request object outside of the initial connect callback no problem. I have accepted your answer though, a connection per query seems to work while a singleton connection object does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the problem lies in the data-base connection (Hence, why it happens when you initiate the app).

I would suggest to have a different module where you do the data-base connection and query logic, and then use it in your route.

A brief suggestion.

have another file called `db.js`, and do something similar to the following:

```
var sql = require("mssql");

// Setup for Azure SQL Server
var config = {
    user: env.username,
    password: env.password,
    server: "mydomain.database.windows.net",
    database: "blog",

    // As per the npm docs, encrypt=true for Azure connections
    options: {
        encrypt: true
    }
};

function query(query, callback){
   sql.connect(config, function(err) {
      if(err) throw err;
      new sql.Request().query(query, function (err, result){
         if(err) throw err;
         callback(result)
      });

   });
}

module.export = {query : query}
```

Then you require the file at your route logic, and you do:

```
var db = require('../db.js');


exports.index = function (req, res) {
var query = "SELECT P.pid, P.title, P.tags, P.topic, P.body_preview FROM Posts P ORDER BY P.date_created DESC";

db.query(query, function (recordset) {

    res.render('index', {
        rows: recordset
    });
```

});

Comment: This did the trick. Very surprising, in many other applications a Singleton DB connection is what you would expect to use, passing around as necessary. I guess with the mssql npm package it has some issues with staying alive? Either way, thank you!